# How to display a pdf in a twig division using ajax and symfony?

Tags: ajax, symfony, pdf

I try to display a pdf in my twig , I created a method in the controller that generate the pdf :

```html
 public function invitationPDFAction(){

        $html = $this->renderView('InvitationInvitationBundle:invitation:indextest.html.twig');
       
        $html2pdf = new \Html2Pdf_Html2Pdf('P','A4','fr');
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetTitle('real');
       // $html2pdf->pdf->SetAuthor('Fz');
 
        $html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');
 
       $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
        $html2pdf->Output('file.pdf');
     $response = new Response();
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type','application/pdf');
     return $response;

    }
```

and an ajax script that return the pdf inside the view :

```html
$.ajax({
                                           type: 'get',
                                           url: "{{ path('invitation_invitationPDF')}}",
                                           beforeSend: function() {
                                              
                                           },
                                           success: function(data) {
                                             $(".page-content").append(data);
                                             $(".modal-body").hide();
                                           }
                                           });
```

but it seems not working , the method generate the pdf , but I can't display it, take a look at the result please : [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is getting the file contents of the PDF with your ajax call, and the content is then displayed in your `.page-content`.

To achieve what you want you should embed the PDF file instead, this can be achieved in a number of ways, the easiest probably being adding the following code inside your `.page-content`

```
<embed src="{{ path('invitation_invitationPDF')}}" width="500" height="400" type='application/pdf'>
```